# Where to store downloaded files in a Flutter App?

Tags: flutter

Im learning Flutter and Im confused where the downloaded files are saved exactly?

For example Im building a mp3 player and Im required to download mp3 file from a URL but I have no idea where to save that mp3 file in case of downloading to iOS and in case of downloading to Android device.

Which is the safest location so that I dont screw up my app's performance?

I spent 2 days trying to figure out an answer for this question but I still dont understand it.

Please help :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs ([reading-writing-files](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files) ) uses path_provider.
Have you checked it out?

The examples are fairly easy to understand: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/path_provider/path_provider/example/lib/main.dart

In your case I'd probably go with

```
getExternalStorageDirectories( StorageDirectory.music )
```

if available.